# timer keeps running after putting thread in wait

Tags: java, multithreading

What is happening here? Whenever I press the start button, it simply starts counting from 00:00:000 on my JLabel (nice, thats what I want). After pressing the stop button say on 00:10:000, I see my JLabel on 00:10:000 (nice, thats what I want to). Okay here comes the problem, whenever I press the start button again, I expect it to start at 00:10:000. But it doesn't, because the counter keeps running on the background. So say my JLabel stands on 00:10:000 and wait for exactly 00:07:000 and press the start button again, it starts counting again from 00:17:000. So can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

```
private boolean isRunning;
private boolean isWaiting;

public void run()
{
    long calibration1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try
    {
        while(isRunning == true) //start button
        {
            long yourmilliseconds1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");

            System.out.println(sdf1.format(yourmilliseconds1 - calibration1));
            String outputTimer = sdf1.format(yourmilliseconds1 - calibration1);

            timerLabel.setText(outputTimer);

            if(isWaiting == true) // stop button        
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    wait(); //if start button is pressed again it will notify() (no need for code)                  }
            }
        }
    }

    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

    }   
}

public void startButton()
{
    isWaiting = false;
    isRunning = true;
}

public void stopButton()
{
    isWaiting = true;
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Use `AtomicBoolean` or make the `boolean` `volatile` (I've found `AtomicBoolean` to be more reliable)

Comment: The volatile doesn't work, but i will try the AtomicBoolean to. thanks for your response

Comment: Oh, I should have also pointed out that you are violating the single thread rules of Swing by update the `timerLabel` outside the content of the Event Dispatching Thread.  The solution would be much simpler and safer if you use a Swing Timer instead.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: The AtomicBoolean doesn't work to, so i am now going to try using Swing Timers. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: You never call `notify` to exit from the `wait` call...But this assumes you only have a single instance of your timer

Comment: I have a method that wake ups the thread with notify, only not showing because this is not related to the problem. I can put the thread in wait and notify it, but when in wait the timer keeps running.

Comment: Then I can only imagine that you have more then one timer.  You really should contain the management of the timer to itself, less messy

Comment: I hacked together a  [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it seems to work, reasonably, well

Comment: I like the link you sent, but I can't accept why my code isn't working. I am stuck for a couple hours now and really want to know why :P. If i know the why, i know how something works. Maybe later i will face exactly the same problem in a other state and then i know why. And i really appreciate your time, your the only one so far with some suggestions (thumbs up!). And i will keep that link in mind for my next programs

Comment: Without a runnable example which demonstrates your problem, it's impossible to know. As I said, once I was able to get a runnable example wrapped around you code, it seemed to work okay for me

Comment: I fixed it, using a while loop that makes a variable called pauseTime.    'String outputTimer = sdf1.format(currentTimeInMillis1 - calibrateToZero1 - pauseTimeTotal);' 'pauseTimeOld += pauseTimeWhenStop;
     calibrateToZero2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
     
     while(isRunning.get() == false)
     {
      currentTimeInMillis2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      pauseTimeWhenStop = currentTimeInMillis2 - calibrateToZero2;
     }
     
     pauseTimeTotal = pauseTimeOld + pauseTimeWhenStop;'

Comment: The problem with this is the while loop while consume CPU cycles, it could potentially run the CPU to 100% and starve other threads